# How to extract dynamic time counter on a web page using python

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a few websites using `BeautifulSoup` in python. I've stumbled across a countdown timer in a website that I want to extract. The timer shows the remaining time of some info on the site. Some javascript method is triggering the `innerHTML` every second. Anybody knows how to extract it?

Comment: This info is not enough to help. You need to tell a little more about HTML and javascript of that page.

Comment: And 'anybody knows how to do it' isn't a good question. You need to tell us what you've tried and at what point you're getting stuck. And yes, a link to the site would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to screen-scrape that, because loads of free Javascript countdown timer codes are but a Google search away. Here's my favourite one by Robert Hashemian: http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm

But if you still want to scrape it, you'd need to look at the HTML source of the website. If the javascript for the timer is embedded in the document, you must find the beginning and ending `<script>` and `</script>` tags and copy everything in between (which essentially defeats the point of automated scraping as you're having to hunt down the script anyway). If the script is in an external js file (which is more likely), it's better to just download the file.

Comment: So far i have been able to get the static content through beautifulsoup but as this is dynamic it returns empty obviously.I have been finding the attribute of the div which contains my data using firebug extension,i dont see the js function in the page may be i have to download the external js file

Comment: for example i want to get the timer which is on the right top corner of this page http://www.snapdeal.com/deal-bangalore_mg_road_plus-tata-photon-blr

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't use available code. But the script for this website is not in the `<head>` at least, or on any immediately visible external file.